# Python program to enter numbers into search box

Tags: python, search, text, barcode, box

I'm brand new to Stack Overflow and I have an intermediate knowledge of Python,Javascript, and HTML.

I'm trying to get pointed in the right direction here. At the library where I work we have a cart containing 30+ ipads, each having a barcode on the back. When someone checks out the cart we have to manually enter/scan all 30 barcodes into a web page that is hosted on our server (typically we have Chrome up when logged into the page).

What I'm trying to do is to write a program that automatically enters all 30+ codes into the search box, hitting "enter" after each one. If possible I would like this to happen after scanning one barcode, then all 30 codes are entered automatically afterward. I was told that Python was the easiest way to go about this. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is JavaScript, not Python. You could write a  small code snippet to do this(fill 30 barcodes), and then execute it in the browser console after checking in one iPad.

Comment: if you mean just to input something into web dialog box using browser, then you can try `Python ` + `SeleniumWebDriver`

Comment: What is the idea behind scanning every barcode? Seems to me like it would be to ensure that all the units are accounted for, in which case having them automatically entered would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I appreciate the feeback! I will give Selenium a look. @TigerhawkT3 in answer to your question, we have a field on our web form that tracks the number of items that user has out at the time, so automating the process won't be a problem because we can account for the units just by looking at the web page

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this using Python would be to use the Selenium WebDriver library. It is fairly straight-forward to use if you have done any work with Selenium before: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

If you haven't worked with Selenium before, you should know that it is basically a tool used by software testers to automate clicking through a webpage. This is why I could see that someone may have steered you in this direction. You will definitely need to brush up on how Selenium works though: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Basically Selenium identifies elements of a website through "selectors" and then performs actions on them. You'll need to find the selectors for your website, such as the selector for your text box and the selector for your submit button.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # this lets webdriver wait 10 seconds for the website to load
driver.get("http://yourwebsite.net")

barcodes = ["123451231", "6789021313", "231927813"]
for barcode in barcodes:
    text_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#input') # input selector
    text_box.send_keys(barcode) # enter text in input

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#submit').click() # click the submit button

driver.quit()
```

Of course I have no idea what the selectors are actually labeled on your website, I took a wild guess here, you'll need to find this part out. Good luck!